# Converting site to HTTPS?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I have a site using apostrophe which is still on http. I want to convert it to https.

What goes into doing so (that is specific to apostrophe)? Are links (specifically js/css/images) on the site hardcoded, or can I make a couple changes and have them automatically convert to https?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apostrophe sites, like almost anything powered by Node.js, are usually deployed behind a reverse proxy like Nginx (recommended) or Apache.

See [hosting Apostrophe in production](http://apostrophecms.org/docs/tutorials/intermediate/deployment.html).

The great thing about this is that if you decide to add HTTPS to the proxy server, nothing has to change at the Apostrophe level.

All the links generated by Apostrophe are site-relative precisely for this reason, however if users are manually creating links in the rich text editor those will of course need some attention.

If you are using [mechanic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mechanic) to manage Nginx, as we recommend, then this gets very easy indeed. Even if not, you just follow standard practices for configuring a secure certificate and the use of HTTPS in Nginx or your reverse proxy of choice.

The "last mile" of the connection, i.e. the proxy connection between Nginx and Apostrophe, is usually on the same server or the same private internal network, so the use of HTTP is OK there and avoids introducing significant performance overhead.